# Is it possible to add a non-breaking space in CreateJS?

Tags: createjs, easeljs, non-breaking-characters

I try to add a non-breaking space when using CreateJS (or EaselJS). But it does not work.
For example: I don't want a linebreak between a "text" and a "!"
Example:

```
this.copy_01 = new cjs.Text("This is a text\u00A0!", "bold 60px 'Times New Roman'", "#FFFFFF");
```

`\u00A0` usually works in JavaScript. But now it only adds a space, but not a non-breaking space.

Does someone know if it is possible to add a non-breaking space in CreateJS?

Answer (score 1):

The line-wrapping in EaselJS is manually implemented in the Canvas, so it doesn't follow the JavaScript ruleset. You would have to manually add support for it. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying a workaround.
Seems to work for me, but I am not really happy with this.

```
function nonBreak(textObj) {
    var origString = textObj.text; 
    var compStr = origString.replace(/(.|[\r\n])*?<nbr>.*?($|\s)/, "");
    compStr = origString.replace(compStr, ""); 
    compStr1 = compStr.replace(/<nbr>/, " "); 
    compStr2 = compStr.replace(/<nbr>/, "\n"); 
    textObj.text = compStr1;
    var sizeStr1 = textObj.getMetrics().height;
    textObj.text = compStr2;
    sizeStr2 = textObj.getMetrics().height;
    textObj.text = origString;

    if (sizeStr1 == sizeStr2) {
        newString1 = origString.replace(/\s?[^ ]*<nbr>.*/, "");
        newString2 = origString.replace(newString1 + " ", "");
        newString1 = newString1 + "\n";
        newString2 = newString2.replace(/<nbr>/, " ");
        newString = newString1 + newString2;
        textObj.text = newString;
    } else {
        newString = origString.replace(/<nbr>/, " ");
        textObj.text = newString;
    }

}




var origString = this.copy_01.text;
var textCopy = this.copy_01;
var countBR = origString.match(/<nbr>/g);
if (countBR !== null) {
    for (i = 0; i < countBR.length; i++) {

        if (countBR[i] == "<nbr>") {
            nonBreak(textCopy);
        }

    }
```

}